# Radio buttons and text on same line

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I am trying to put a bunch of radio buttons in a form. Each has a label, and all the way to the right of the label should be an X (hence the `class:pull-right`). For some reason, each time I add a new radio button, the X gets pulled more and more towards the center of the form. Here is the code; see link below for what it produces. Can someone please explain what is happening/how I can fix the alignments? Note: each successive X is shifting by an additional 8px, which happens to be the border-radius of the form; not sure if this is just a coincidence.

Edit: what I have tried: putting each set of input/label/p tags in its own row, and also span; neither worked. I have tried playing with the pull-right class but when I remove it, the X's actually get sent to the next line below.

```
<form style="border:2px black solid; border-radius: 8px; padding:5px;">

<input style="margin-left:5px;line-height:30px" id="labelA" type="radio" name="letter"   value="A" checked="true"></input>
<label for="labelA" style="font weight:normal">A</label>
<p class="pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;line-height:25px;">X</p>
<br>

<input style="margin-left:5px;line-height:30px" id="labelB" type="radio" name="letter" value="B" checked="true"></input>
<label for="labelB" style="font weight:normal">B</label>
<p class="pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;line-height:25px;">X</p>
<br>`

<input style="margin-left:5px;line-height:30px" id="labelC" type="radio" name="letter"   value="C" checked="true"></input>
<label for="labelC" style="font weight:normal">C</label>
<p class="pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;line-height:25px;">X</p>

</form>
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdwUX.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the styles just to show what I did in a simple manner.

Generally I would not recommend using `pull-right/left` as it's effects will occur down the ENTIRE HTML until you call something like `div class="clear" />`.

Just use `float` if possible.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/w4gdtkfe/)**

**HTML**

```
<form style="border:2px black solid; border-radius: 8px;">
<input id="labelA" type="radio" name="letter" value="A" checked="true" />
<span>A</span>
<span class="x">X</span>
<br>

<input id="labelB" type="radio" name="letter" value="B" checked="true" />
<span>B</span>
<span class="x">X</span>
<br>

<input id="labelC" type="radio" name="letter"   value="C" checked="true" />
<span >C</span>
<span class="x">X</span>

</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.x {
    float:right
}
```

Some further advice, one thing I have learned is if I am having issues styling stuff and I am jamming styles on individual elements, I am most likely thinking wayyy to hard on it. Try to keep CSS simple. :)

Comment: Thank you! I suspected the pull-right had something to do with it. Also +1 for simplicity for removing the label element and just having the text

Comment: @pwerth `pull-right` has its uses, but for the most part it should very rarely be used and only after floating/padding/margining does not work. :)